# loop through all entities with LINQ to Entities

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have n entities and some of them have a property that with the same name in all of them.

Is there a way in Linq to Entities where I can loop through all my entities and check on whether they have a property and if they do then do something with them?

I want to do this (pseudo code)

```
foreach(var entity in myEntities.entities)
{
    If (entity has property)
    {
        Var query = from q in entity where property= “99” select q;
        ….
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I guess another way of saying this is that instead of doing this:

```
var cars = from c in Entities.Cars where Colour = "white" select c;
var fruits = from f in Entities.Fruits where Colour = "white" select f;
....
```

I want to be able to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
var colouredEntities = GetAllEntitiesThatContainPropertyColour();
foreach(var colouredEntity in colouredEntities)
{
     var entity= from f in Entities.colouredEntity where Colour = "white" select e;
}
```

Comment: Linq to Entities and Entity Framework are meant to let you work with, well, *Entities* (classes). You should not think in terms of tables and foreign keys but rather in terms of objects and their relationship.

Comment: ok fair point, but what I need to achieve doesn't change - it's the same concept. I'll update the question

Comment: Can we clarify if 'foreign key' is a specific named property or a property that is defined as a foreign key?

Comment: it could be both a foreign key or just a named property.

Comment: So you want to loop through every entity of every type in your project? That kinda sounds like an X-Y problem, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to find all instances of a property across all the entities and then select the data of each instance

Comment: So, for example, if you had a system with `Cars`, `Fruit` and `DaysOfWeek` and you want all values for `Colour` property, you would select all `Cars` and `Fruit` but not `DaysOfWeek`?

Comment: yeah that's it. I would select all Cars and Fruit that contain a spefic "Colour". Then what I want to achieve is to duplicate these entities with a different colour.

Answer (score 0):

So to achieve the 'if (entity has property)' can be achieved via reflection.

The following code would check whether the entity has a property with a foreign key attribute.

```
var hasKey = (from prop in entity.GetType().GetProperties() where Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(ForeignKeyAttribute)) == true select true).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you wanted to do it by name then the following code would suffice.

```
var hasName = (from prop in entity.GetType().GetProperties() where prop.Name == "APropertyOfYourChoosing" select true).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanks. how would you return the actual content of the entity and not true/false?

Comment: Give me a few mins, and I will add a further example.